# permission denied npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

So today is a Monday, that's for sure. allllllll that I did was run the command
`$ sudo rm -r node_modules/ package-lock.json` and then from there I went to run the command `$ npm i` to reinstall the dependencies. From there I got the error saying that I don't have permission:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/c.francia/Desktop/application/app/node_modules/@types
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/c.francia/Desktop/application/app/node_modules/@types'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/c.francia/Desktop/application/app/node_modules/@types'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/c.francia/Desktop/application/app/node_modules/@types'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/c.francia/Desktop/application/app/node_modules/@types'
npm ERR! }
```

I tried the command `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm` that was suggested and widely accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo) and also tried `$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules` as suggested [here](https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/) I had this error before but the first solution resolved it for me. So I have no idea what has changed from removing node_modules and the package-lock.json file

Answer (score 0):

If the first solution worked for you, then the permissions in `.npm` were not set correctly. Now that your permissions are resolved, try to avoid using `sudo` with `npm` commands in the future.

Comment: This should probably be a comment

Comment: You said "the first solution resolved it for me." What exactly is your question?